# Can Kubernetes RoleBinding have subjects in a different namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount

RoleBinding subjects do have a `namespace` field, but when i create a RoleBinding in one namespace with subject in another, it doesn't seem it works.

Full example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace1

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace2

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-sa
  namespace: namespace1

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
  namespace: namespace2
type: Opaque
data:
  foo: "Zm9vCg=="

---
 
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: test-secret-reader
  namespace: namespace2
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secret"]
  verbs: ["get"]
 
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-secret-reader
  namespace: namespace2
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: test-secret-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-sa
  namespace: namespace1
```

Test with `kubectl auth can-i`:

```bash
$ kubectl auth can-i get secret -n namespace2 --as system:serviceaccount:namespace1:test-sa
no
```

Comment: No, a RoleBinding cannot reference a subject in a different namespace. RoleBindings are namespace-scoped and can only grant access within their own namespace. To grant cross-namespace permissions, use a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding, which are cluster-scoped and can grant access across all namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that Roles and RoleBindings are namespace scoped resources, they can be used to authorize access to subjects in different namespaces.

The issue with example in question is that rule resources must be **in plural**:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: test-secret-reader
  namespace: namespace2
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

Full example:
https://gist.github.com/draganHR/d073d41fc119c8625fa505a5052b133e
(Tested on Kubernetes 1.27+).